# How can I fetch a Type from Method Parameter and then pass it into the Generic Class in java?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Class:

```java
@Data
public class Dummy {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
}
```

Method:

```java
public void m(List<List<Dummy>> object) {

}
```

JSON:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name": "John"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name": "Bryan"
        }
    ]
]
```

Now, my question is -

I am currently building a framework. So, I get this method at runtime.

I am currently parsing the JSON using Jackson Library through `new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<List<Dummy>>>(){})`. It is possible because I am giving the generic type to `TypeReference` beforehand, which will not be the case because I would not be knowing the Type before. It will come to me in the runtime.

How to fetch the type from the method and then pass it into the generics of the  `TypeReference` in runtime using reflection?

I tried something like this -

```java
private <T> T testObject(T object, String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
     return (T) new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<T>(){});
}


List<List<Dummy>> obj = (List<List<Dummy>>) testObject((ParameterizedType)methodParam[i].getParameterizedType(), json)
```

But still I am getting as List<List<LinkedHashmap<String, String>>> something like this.

Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: I assume you have access to the Method object of the above method, you could try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes--  to get the parameter type through reflection. For a somewhat similar example, refer https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/2.14/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.java

Comment: I already referred to these documents. I didn't find any solutions.

Comment: From the method getGenericParameterTypes. Extend TypeReference and return the Type obtained from the method from getType, you could try and check